# Angular 4 для asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular2

Можно ли и как использовать angular 4 с asp.net mvc, на iis.

Comment: Да, но лучше в отдельных проектах. По опыту могу сказать что лучше IDE для Asp.NEt вы не найдете чем Visual Studio, а для Angular - WebStorm. И не Asp.Net MVC, а лучше ASP.NET WebApi

Comment: А как использовать на одном сайте, nodejs хостит на одном, iis на другом. Для core можно использовать dotnet start, но у меня ошибки есть

Comment: Всё банально просто и хостится на IIS спокойно, только нужно для IIS модули для запуска NodeJS найти. Запускается angular приложение не с проектом Asp.Net Core а отдельным приложением и командой ng serve

Answer (score 0):

Родной средой для проектов на Angular является Visual Studio Code
но разумеется есть возможность использовать Visual Studio 2017 или WebStorm

1) Необходимо установить [**TypeScript**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links)

2) а также **Node.JS**

3) Необходимо установить **NPM** версии 5 или выше

4) Устанавливаем готовый шаблон проекта от сообщества - Angular5TemplateCore

Открываем Visual Studio 2017 и идем в File -> New project. Выбираем раздел Online из меню с проектами, затем Visual C#. Из списка ищем и выбираем Angular5TemplateCore и нажимаем OK.

[image: Поиск шаблона приложение в магазине шаблонов]

Закрываем Visual Studio и дожидаемся установки шаблона Angular5TemplateCore. После того как установка выполнена, наступило время построить приложение на  Angular 5 на ядре ASP.NET Core. Подробнее в описании ниже.

5) Создаем приложение

В студии New >> Project. Далее Visual C# >> выбираем Angular5Core2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда проект будет создан, мы можем открыть Solution Explorer где можно увидеть
примеры компонентов Angular5, HTML, и приложение в папке ClientApp, лежащей на уровне ASP.NET Core папки с контроллерами Controllers и View.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6) Нужно собрать и запустить приложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]